# populate spinner from DB, Retrieve Selected Spinner Value and save to SQL DB

Tags: java, php, android

I am building a bus location app. I am trying to get selected value from a spinner. Note the spinner was populated from DB, however, when I try to get the selected value of the spinner my app crashes. I want to get the selected value from the spinner and send it to my DB.

```
public class 
DriversLocationUpdate extends AppCompatActivity implements AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener{

    ArrayList<String> listitems1= new ArrayList<> ();
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter1;
    ArrayList<String> listitems2= new ArrayList<> ();
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter2;

    Spinner busListArray, locationListArray;
    ProgressBar progressbar;
    Button btnUpd;
    String currselectedBus, logstatus, currselectedLocat;
    TextView vtxtValidation;
    TextView res1,res2;
    //String[] arrayUserinfo;
    @Override

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_drivers_location_update);

        progressbar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.loginprogress);
        res1=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.spin1);
        res2=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.spin2);

        busListArray = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.bus_arrays);
        adapter1 = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, R.layout.support_simple_spinner_dropdown_item, listitems1);
        busListArray.setAdapter(adapter1);
        locationListArray = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.location_arrays) ;
        adapter2 = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, R.layout.support_simple_spinner_dropdown_item, listitems2);
        locationListArray.setAdapter(adapter2);

        busListArray.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
        locationListArray.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
        btnUpd = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnLocUpdt);
        btnUpd.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                currselectedBus=res1.getText().toString();
                currselectedLocat=res2.getText().toString();
                new LocationUpdateClass().execute( currselectedBus, currselectedLocat);
            }
        });
    }

    protected void onStart(){
        super.onStart();
        backTask1 bt1 = new backTask1();
        bt1.execute();
        backTask2 bt2 = new backTask2();
        bt2.execute();
    }

    private class backTask1 extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>{
        ArrayList<String> list;

        protected  void onPreExecute (){
            super.onPreExecute();
            list = new ArrayList<>();
        }

        protected  Void doInBackground(Void...params){
            InputStream is=null;
            String result ="";
            try {
                HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost("http://livetipsdotnet.000webhostapp.com/fetchspinner1.php");
                HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
                HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                is = entity.getContent();
            }
            catch (IOException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            try {
                BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is,"UTF-8"));
                String line="";
                while ((line=bufferedReader.readLine())!=null)
                {
                    result +=line;
                }
                is.close();
            }
            catch (IOException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            try {
                JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(result);
                for (int i=0; i<jsonArray.length(); i++)
                {
                    JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                    list.add(jsonObject.getString("id"));
                }
            }catch (JSONException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return  null;
        }

        protected  void onPostExecute (Void result){
            listitems1.addAll(list);
            adapter1.notifyDataSetChanged();
            progressbar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    }//end of first spinner class

    private class backTask2 extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>{
        ArrayList<String> list;

        protected  void onPreExecute (){
            super.onPreExecute();
            list = new ArrayList<>();
        }

        protected  Void doInBackground(Void...params){
            InputStream is=null;
            String result ="";
            try {
                HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost("http://livetipsdotnet.000webhostapp.com/fetchspinner2.php");
                HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
                HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                is = entity.getContent();
            }
            catch (IOException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            try {
                BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is,"UTF-8"));
                String line="";
                while ((line=bufferedReader.readLine())!=null)
                {
                    result +=line;
                }
                is.close();
            }
            catch (IOException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            try {
                JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(result);
                for (int i=0; i<jsonArray.length(); i++)
                {
                    JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                    list.add(jsonObject.getString("name"));
                }
            }catch (JSONException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return  null;
        }

        protected  void onPostExecute (Void result){
            listitems2.addAll(list);
            adapter2.notifyDataSetChanged();
            progressbar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    }

    public class LocationUpdateClass extends AsyncTask<String,Void,String> {
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            String busID = params[0];
            String busLoc = params[1];
            String link = "http://livetipsdotnet.000webhostapp.com/buslocationupdt.php?busID="
                    + busID + "&busLoc=" + busLoc;
            try {
                OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
                RequestBody postData = new FormBody.Builder()
                        .add("type", "json")
                        .build();
                Request request = new Request.Builder()
                        .url(link)
                        .post(postData)
                        .build();
                Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
                String result = response.body().string();
                return result;
            } catch (Exception e) {
                return e.getMessage().toString();
            }
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String getResult) {
            super.onPostExecute(getResult);
            DriversLocationUpdate.this.logstatus = getResult;
            vtxtValidation.setText(getResult);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View selectedItemView, int position, long id) {
        switch (parent.getId()){
            case R.id.bus_arrays:
                String list1 = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
                res1.setText(list1);
                Toast.makeText(parent.getContext(), "OnItemSelectedListener : " + list1, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;
            case R.id.location_arrays:
                String list2 = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
                res2.setText(list2);
                Toast.makeText(parent.getContext(), "OnItemSelectedListener : " + list2, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_drivers_location_update, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        int id = item.getItemId();
        return id == R.id.action_settings || super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                  Process: tosan.example.tosan.buslocation, PID: 11451
                  java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference
                      at tosan.example.tosan.buslocation.DriversLocationUpdate$LocationUpdateClass.onPostExecute(DriversLocationUpdate.java:224)
                      at tosan.example.tosan.buslocation.DriversLocationUpdate$LocationUpdateClass.onPostExecute(DriversLocationUpdate.java:196)
                      at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:660)
                      at android.os.AsyncTask.-wrap1(AsyncTask.java)
                      at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:677)
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6682)
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1520)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1410)

Comment: `my app crashes`. Is it a `guess the Exception quiz?`. See http://idownvotedbecau.se/noexceptiondetails/.

Comment: Hi, maybe you should provide the console error log that you are getting when the app crashes, or at least try to debug the code in runtime to see what's the line in which it crashes. With a more specific question it will be much more easy for anyone to help you with your problem. Thanks

Comment: Thanks, @Hugo your suggestion saved me. From the error log, I could sort out the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

```
final Spinner spinner = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner);
spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {

    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {

        String items = spinner.getSelectedItem().toString();
       //Here give a network call
    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {

    }

});
```